# Problem with csv data imported on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm new on this site so be indulgent if i make a mistake :)
I recently imported a csv file on my Jupyter notebook for a student work. I want use some of data of specific column of this file. The problem is that after import, the file appear as a table with 5286 lines (which represent dates and hours of measures) in a single column (that compiles all variables separated by ; that i want use for my work).
I don't know how to do to put this like a regular table.
I used this code  to import my csv from my board :

```py
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv('/work/Weather_data/data 1998-2003.csv','error_bad_lines = false')
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Desired output: the same data in multiple columns, separated on `;`.

Comment: maybe you could try this pandas.read_csv(...... , sep = ';' ). There are many examples available in here https://thispointer.com/pandas-read-csv-file-to-dataframe-with-custom-delimiter-in-python/

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('<location>', sep=';')
```